# unicode() vs. str.decode() for a utf8 encoded byte string (python 2.x)

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Is there any reason to prefer `unicode(somestring, 'utf8')` as opposed to `somestring.decode('utf8')`?

My only thought is that `.decode()` is a bound method so python may be able to resolve it more efficiently, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's easy to benchmark it:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> ts = Timer("s.decode('utf-8')", "s = 'ééé'")
>>> ts.timeit()
8.9185450077056885
>>> tu = Timer("unicode(s, 'utf-8')", "s = 'ééé'") 
>>> tu.timeit()
2.7656929492950439
>>>
```

Obviously, `unicode()` is faster.

FWIW, I don't know where you get the impression that methods would be faster - it's quite the contrary.

Comment: Python25: 3.0 vs. 0.9; Python26: 2.6 vs. 0.6 that is `unicode()` is about 4 time faster than `s.decode()`

Comment: Is there something similar to `encode`? Need it for fast hashing of unicode strings.

Comment: @delijati not in Python 2.x AFAIK - but do you really need to encode your unicode string to byte string for hashing ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers `hashlib.md5(u"höömaa".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()` without encode it would crash. I use `mmh3.hash128` to generate fast hashes but `encode` slows it to much down.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 4x is a huge and unexpected difference here — any idea where does it come from?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: I can reproduce it on Python 2.7 (no difference on Python 3). The difference is noticable only for smal strings. For `s*100000` both are the same. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 23):

I'd prefer `'something'.decode(...)` since the `unicode` type is no longer there in Python 3.0, while `text = b'binarydata'.decode(encoding)` is still valid.

Comment: Great point. Also, do note that strings are unicode by default in python 3 http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html